# Django DataError index out of range with postrgresql

Tags: django, postgresql, psycopg2

Good evening,

I realise that this question may have been asked in the past, but I am getting the following errors

"psycopg2.errors.NumericValueOutOfRange: integer out of range"
and
"django.db.utils.DataError: integer out of range"

when using postgresql with Django.

Other responses to similar queries all seem to suggest that I am reaching very large id's or pk's. This is not the case. My database is very small, and I am just trying to save objects to it, and I cannot possibly be reaching 2^31-1 id's. Some objects save ok, others do not and raise the error. There seems to be no pattern to it, and its infuriating.

I have until recently been using sqlite for this, and I have never ever had this problem.

I am new to postgresql but the database exists, is migrated to successfully and I can see the fields inside pgAdmin.

The project is quite complex and I am unable to provide a minimum reproducible example without posting much code, but I am happy to elaborate.

What could possibly by the reason for the above?

Portion of models.py as requested:

```
class Requirement(models.Model):
    module = models.ForeignKey(Module, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
    signups = models.ManyToManyField('Student', through='SignUp', blank=True)
    etc.

class Student(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False)
    signups = models.ManyToManyField('Requirement', through='SignUp')
    etc.

class Signup(models.Model):
    requirement = models.ForeignKey(Requirement, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True) 
    etc.
```

Comment: could you show your model?

Comment: Hi there! I have quite a lot in my models.py file, but the problem happens when trying to save an object that is an instance of a 'through' table.

Comment: Apologies, how does one post code?

Comment: You start with ``` and end with ```. inside of it will become code block

Comment: when creating a Singup object, calling .save() is what triggers the error. There have not been 2^31-1 of these before.

Comment: You mean like id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)? I had tried that, it did not change the behaviour. The primary key is generated automatically, I understand?

Comment: Data in one of your integer fields is likely larger than allowed, I don't think it's the db key that's too big.

Comment: That's impossible. There may be at most a hundred instances of what I'm trying to create. I don't see how I can reach anything like long ints here.

Comment: I think what @Ben meant is that if you have some interger field, the number in that field might exceeded. But I do not see any intergerfield in your model....

Comment: It's not the pk that's too big, it's something like a phone number in an integerField that is larger than 2147483647. Maybe a student ID or class ID?

Comment: Oh I see. There are also PositiveIntegerFields (but they do not contain such large numbers), CharFields, BooleanFields, EmailFields...

Comment: Is the only possible cause of this error that whatever is inside the integerfield is too large? Can there be no other cause for it?

Comment: There may be other reasons, but this is an error I've seen personally, and that was the cause.

Comment: Yes, all the other internet comments on this topic have also suggested this cause, but I don't think this is what I have.

Comment: just to be a safe side, how about if you change intergerfield to BigIntergerfield, and see if this error disappears?

Comment: What is the actual query/code that is triggering the error?

Comment: I will try that. Thank you.

Comment: Hello, I believe that BigIntegerField has fixed it. I am not sure how. At least it hasn't triggered the error in the few tests I have done. If this is it, then I am enormously grateful.

Comment: My, glad it worked out for you. I am curious what you are saving, why the data exceeded Intergerfield limit?!

Comment: Take a look at your newly saved data for those BigIntegerFields... there you will find the answer you seek.

Comment: It was a random personal identifier, clearly much larger than I had given it credit for. It never triggered this issue with sqlite3 which is why it didn't occur to me. All the other comments were suggesting that the pk would be large and I was trying to understand how that could be possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you enable django logging with:

```py
LOGGING = {
    # ...
    'loggers': {
        # ...
        'django.db': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        },
    },
}
```

in the django settings, or look at the database logs, you will probably find the number and field that is causing your error.